# DOM Scrape not working PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, scrape

I was just wondering why this isnt working for me.  What i want to do is strip out the m4v file.  I have a similar script working for images on my site that will strip the image, upload to dir and database and link.  but i cant get this to work the same way.  Thanks for your help

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("http://www.mysitesvids.com/m/videos/view/36821");
$element = $html->find("file:");
$result = $element->innertext;

?>
```

This is the code from the site

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jwplayer ('embedFlashPlayer').setup         ({flashplayer:'/swf/jwplayer5.swf',id:'moviePlayer',width:602,height:404,
    file:'http://davesvideos.mysitevids.com/media/b0e9ec18eb567ce41dce906cee7e1c9f/4fcbb164/videos/m/634276.m4v',
image:'/media/80eb2eaca3c58f002be8ab5bda476e91/4fcbb164/videos/p/64/634276.jpg',
provider:'http',controlbar:'bottom',stretching:'uniform',abouttext:'mysite',aboutlink:'http://www.eroprofile.com/'});

glbUpdViews ('0','634276','0','0');
ajaxActive = false;
cmtLoad ('video', '634276', '', '');
ajaxActive = false;
cmtReply ('video', '634276', '0');


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easier solved with a regular expression:

```
preg_match( "/file:'(.+?)'/", $html, $matches );

if ( $matches ) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

I'm assuming you don't have other instances of this string pattern on the page. if you did, and you only wanted to match the m4v's, you could modify the expression to look for that extension:

```
preg_match( "/file:'(.+?\.m4v)'/", $html, $matches );

if ( $matches ) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From docs of SimpleHtmlDom, `find()` matches only html elements, hence you cannot search for 'file:' using `find()`, you can probably do this:

```
$script = $html->find('script')->innertext
```

and apply a regular expression to match *.mv4 file on `$script`.

alternatively, you can apply the regex matching directly on contents of file.

Comment: <?php

    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html =   file_get_html("http://www.mysitesvids.com/m/videos/view/36821");
    $script = $html->find('script')->innertext

    ?>

Comment: `$script` will contain the complete text inside `<script>...</script>`, you will have to add some regular expression matching to get the required url check out [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)